# Maximum consecutive one’s starting and ending index in a binary array in C++

Tags: c++

How to find the starting & ending position (or) index of the longest consecutive 1's in a binary array

EX: 110011110011 -> Starting position is 4 & Ending position is 7

Comment: Just iterate through it and keep track of longest and current sequence of ones, and update longest when you find a longer sequence. But SO is not a code writing service, questions which just ask someone to write your code for you generally get downvoted and closed.

Comment: What does the question have to do with C++ programming?  It is clearly an algorithms question and the answer doesn't depend on the programming language used.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
    #include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int longest = 0;
    int stpos = 0;
        int lpos = 0;
    string s = "110011110011";
    for(int i=0; i<s.length();){
        char current = s[i];
        int currLen = 0;

        for(;i<s.length() && current == s[i]; ++i){
            ++currLen;
            stpos = i;}
        if(currLen > longest){
            longest = currLen ;
            lpos = stpos;}
    }

    cout<<"longest streak length:"<<longest<<endl;;
    cout<<"starting index:"<<lpos-longest+1<<endl;
    cout<<"ending index:"<<lpos<<endl;;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
longest streak length:4
starting index:4
ending index:7
```

Comment: Thanks for the replying, could you please explain why the declaration was avoided in second for loop

Comment: @vinodkumar I want to initialize the second loop with the current value of 'i' coming from the first loop that's why it is not initialized. As an alternative, you can write 'for(i;i<s.length() && current == s[i]; ++i)'

Comment: Code is printing index of 0 if the string has more number of 0's than 1's, could you please help me out to print only the index for 1's

Answer (score -1):

You can try this simple code.I assume the array if of length 12.

```
int arr[12];
int lower=0;
int upper=0;
int max_count=0;
int count=0;
for(int i=0;i<12;i++)
{   
    if(arr[i]==1)
    {
        count++;
    }
    else
    {
        if(max_count<count)
        {
            lower=i-count;
            max_count=count;
            upper=i-1;
            count=0;

        }
    }
}
```